# How to make scopes that actually magnify using materials like glass?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency

I have been trying to create a scope (sniper scope) that actually uses glass shaped like a lens to magnify into objects (I know this is not conventional and not how they do it in normal fps games but I wanted to try this out). It wasn't entirely successful as when I tried to magnify it more, more I increased the IOR the more distorted it got. I've probably got something wrong, and is it even possible to do this, is there a way to fix this?
Basically do any of you have any idea on how to approach this as I think im on the wrong track.

Comment: I think that can work, but you will have to make a lens (like in real)... and probably you'll need some subdivisions (or else, bad effects on the borders). IOR may stay close to normal glass. I mean move (scale) the lens shape instead of changing IOR

Comment: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longue-vue

Comment: Thanks so much, it kinda worked, minor adjustments to the lens I made didn't affect. So fed up, I went out and used a sphere and subdivided it, when I set IOR to 1.5 of glass it was too distorted, but what I noticed is from IOR 1.03-1.08 or somewhere around that range the image is kind of clear and magnified, so thanks, but the small issue being due to the image was distorted in the sense it was less magnified on the outsides and more towards the middle of the image, but thats down to the shape- its clear enough anyway.

Comment: happy that was useful. But **you** did all the job ! Consider to answer your own question : that can be useful for many people

Comment: You might want to take a look at this page, too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photographic_lens_design If you want to build a lens that bends light and magnifies like a real one, you really should pattern it after a real one. Real telescopes and camera lenses usually have between 5 and 20 individual pieces of glass. Designing a telescope is not for the faint of heart.

Answer (score 1):

It is posibbly to do it. Try building a Kepler or a Galilei scope. A kepler scope is easy to build, but the image is inverted. Here is one I made:

[image]

To zoom, scale up the objective lens along the point where the empty is located, or scale down all the other objects along that point. The background image is missing, replace it with anything to see the sope working.

Answer (score 0):

Half sphere in front of Suzanne
[image: Half Sphere]

If you want to create a scope with Cycles you will have to do lots of research or you could cheat and do two renders, each with a different FOV, and use the compositor to add them together. The biggest problem will probably be the amount of memory the glass in the scope will use before you will get a decent quality.

**When you are finished with your scope, try to get a job as a hunting scope designer.**