# How to make a lens?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency, glass

I wanted to make a magnifying glass in blender. I added in a circle and gave it a little thickness. Gave it a casual glass shader too. But all I got was this:

[image]

[image]

There is no magnification at all. Does anyone know how to make a lens that actually magnifies ? I would also like to know how to control the power of the lens.

**EDIT**-

I understand that you need a curved surface for the bending of light but how do I make a curved lens? I'm newbie to blender sorry if this question sounds stupid.

Comment: As in real life the flat glass doesn't have any magnificion, you have to make a curved surface.

Comment: No changing the IOR doesn't do make any magnification

Comment: also related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56812/can-i-model-a-double-convex-lens?r=SearchResults&s=3|50.8195  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60804/how-to-make-scopes-that-actually-magnify-using-materials-like-glass?r=SearchResults&s=5|37.4996

Comment: Gist of the post I've linked: It's the IOR + a lens-shaped object... as in the real world of physics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens -> [How to model a lens?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/56812/31447)

Comment: Thanks for the effort , I searched the community but couldnt find the appropriate question which explained my question. That's why I decided to post this as a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 way to get a magnifying lens.

1. Flat a sphere(with [subdivision surface](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.82/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html?highlight=subdivision) modifiers) it will act as a magnifying lens
2. If you need to get lens from flat surface,

   - Add new material to the lens
   - Open shader editor
   - Add glass BSDF, and connect BSDF to surface in material output
   - Make IOR value to 1.5
   - Next add texture coordinate(input for normal)
   - At last connect reflection  to normal to get lens material.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use the image that I send. It will easy for you. Good luck 

Comment: Please don't use your phone to take photos from the screen, they are hard to see. Use screen captures. From within blender go to the top menu and select: Window > **Save Screenshot**.

Comment: Hi. https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/ should help with taking clearer screenshots. The current ones are quite hard to see. Thanks.

Comment: @Alex Matt that is not the proper way to make a lens. It might do the job but can look weird from different angles and wouldn't magnify the image pretty much. U wouldn't have the control over the magnification(power) as well. Also in this post you can edit by adding a screenshot .

Comment: The proper way I would recommend is the way said here - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56812/can-i-model-a-double-convex-lens